# asynchronousSocketChannel writes and interrupts other part of program

Tags: java, sockets, nio

I am writing java NIO,AsynchronousSocketChannel. In "complete", by default most programmers use this code:

```
while(asynchronousSocketChannel.read( buffer ).get() != -1)
```

This code cause to wait for respond of the server, but I want to customise it and don't wait for the server, I mean I want to do something else and after that check if there's written or not like below:

```
while(true){
 if(asynchronousSocketChannel.read( buffer ).get() != -1){
  //do something
 }
 else{
  //do something else
 }
```

I try a bunch of different algorithm, but it does not work. Is anybody have some idea?

Comment: Please produce your evidence for the claim that most programmers use this code.  It is a complete waste of time to use asynchronous sockets in a completely synchronous manner like this. It would be simpler to use blocking mode NIO, or `java.net.Socket`.

Comment: "In a synchronous I/O operation, a thread enters into action and waits until the I/O request is completed (the program is “stuck” waiting for the process to end, with no way out). When the same action occurs in an asynchronous environment, a thread performs the I/O operation with more kernel help. Actually, it immediately passes the request to the kernel and continues on to process another job." by reading this, I assume that asynchronous is could be better choice for my system which is going to be BIG. I don't understand why my case assume as "completely synchronous manner" in your opinion?

Answer (score 0):

You should post the read, do the 'something else', and then fetch the result of the read future.

Comment: sorry, I want to ask you to mention it more clear, the thing that I am completely sure is that, when I use some server that responds to this client (the client is Asynchronous Client (Based on CompletionHandler)) the code will run (it should be run, because the asynchronousSocketChannel.read( buffer ).get() is not -1 anymore) but if the server not responding him, the program will stop completely. for me it is really strange behaviour, especially when I see this example in a reliable book